# Classic ASP / Persits ASPPDF Multiple pages

Tags: asp-classic, pdf-generation

I've been using persits asppdf modul for about half a year but now I've run into a problem.
I'm using it to make bills with and now i have one that extends over two pages and that is turning out to be a problem because i cant figure out how to continue onto the next page.

Comment: Post your code and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The manual of asppdf states:
HTML allows page breaks for printing purposes via the CSS properties page-break-before and page-break-after. The ImportFromUrl method recognizes these properties for the purpose of page breaking in a limited set of HTML tags. The value for these two properties must be set to "always", other values will have no effect. Just like with any CSS property, inline syntax or a separate style sheet can be used. For example:

```
<BR style="page-break-before: always">
```

The property page-break-before: always can be applied to the following tags:

```
<BR>
<IMG>
<HR>
<TABLE>
<DIV>
```

The property page-break-after: always can be applied to the following tags:

```
<BR>
<IMG>
<HR>
```